# How to publish "Web App" on Appsource.Microsoft.com?

Tags: web-applications, office365, publish, appsource

I want to publish a **Web App** on **Appsource** so that they appear on the page:

[Appsource-WebAppsCategory](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps?src=Office&page=1&product=web-apps)

I would really appreciate help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to submit a request [here](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/partners/list-an-app). The basic requirement is that your application signs in work accounts via Azure Active Directory. More information in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-appsource-certified).